# Tag-like behavior for org-mode plain list items

Tags: emacs, tags, org-mode

I have plain description lists under several different headlines in an `org-mode` file. I know that tags work only for headlines, but I'm looking for analogous functionality for items in these plain lists. Specifically, I want to somehow "tag" certain individual items of the various plain lists and then compile all of those "tagged" items in a separate buffer.

One option is to append some string to each desired item and then use `C-c a s` to search for that string. But doing so only outputs a list of headlines that contain the marked plain list items, not a list of the items themselves. (Another option is to convert the plain lists to headlines themselves and then use real tags, but I'd really prefer leaving them as plain lists.)

Does anybody see a solution? I'm pretty new to `org-mode`, so it might be pretty straightforward. Thanks.

Comment: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode‎

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the link, but I'm not seeing how it helps here. I am trying to "tag" items in a plain list, not headlines ("tag" is in quotes because the formal org-mode tags only work for headlines). The link only discusses excluding/including headline tags. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: This is the link to the official orgmode list. I posted it, so you can ask your question there (see the Action dropdown in the corner) if you don't get an answer here. Here's the gnu mailing list page if you are more familiar with that: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode

Comment: @Tom Oh sorry I misunderstood. I wasn't familiar with either list, so thanks a lot!